# How can I resolve: "Warning: CS0472" during chacking the condition(not for int values)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
private static Sprite[] BusyPlaces = new Sprite[9];

private int[,] WAYS_TO_WIN = new int[8, 3]
{
    {0, 1, 2},
    {3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8},
    {0, 3, 6},
    {1, 4, 7},
    {2, 5, 8},
    {0, 4, 8},
    {2, 4, 6}
};

private void Winner() 
{
    int[] arr = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < WAYS_TO_WIN.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WAYS_TO_WIN.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            arr[j] = WAYS_TO_WIN[i, j];
        }

        
        if (BusyPlaces[arr[0]] == BusyPlaces[arr[1]] == BusyPlaces[arr[2]] != null)
        {
            announce_winner.text = "Winner";
        }
    }
}
```

When I click one of **GameObjects**, it's sprite adding to array `BusyPlaces`.It's abvious that this array has null values default. But when I check it in `if` condition it says that `bool` can't be null, while I'm checking Sprite values.
I read about this problem in chrome, but there was about `int` values.
How can I resolve this warning?

Comment: What is the logic that that `if` statement is supposed to be implementing? Are you trying to see whether any of the three specified elements in the array are `null`? If so then you don't do it like that. You would need to compare each one to `null` directly and use `||` or `&&` operators. You might take some time to brush up on your Boolean logic.

Comment: No, I'm trying to check that these elements are equal(Sprites) and none of these elements are null

Comment: Maybe you should have specified that in the question. Maybe you should edit the question and specify it now. Checking whether two references are equal and checking whether a reference is not `null` are separate operations.

Comment: What is a `Sprite`, a class or a struct? When you do an equality check, are you sure about the correct result? The default equality check for classes is "do these point to the same memory address", not "are all properties the same"

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this:

```cs
if (BusyPlaces[arr[0]] == BusyPlaces[arr[1]] == BusyPlaces[arr[2]] != null)
```

should be this:

```cs
if (BusyPlaces[arr[0]] != null &&
    BusyPlaces[arr[1]] != null &&
    BusyPlaces[arr[2]] != null)
```

You could also throw some LINQ at it, although this is probably a bit advanced for someone who doesn't know basic Boolean logic:

```cs
if (arr.All(i => BusyPlaces[i] != null))
```

EDIT:

Checking for equality is separate to checking for `null`, so the previous code can remain. You just need to add the equality part. This makes no sense:

```cs
BusyPlaces[arr[0]] == BusyPlaces[arr[1]] == BusyPlaces[arr[2]]
```

because the first equality comparison will yield a `bool`, i.e. `true` or `false`, so that's never going to be equal to a third `Sprite`. This will do the job:

```cs
if (BusyPlaces[arr[0]] != null &&
    BusyPlaces[arr[0]] == BusyPlaces[arr[1]] &&
    BusyPlaces[arr[0]] == BusyPlaces[arr[2]])
```

Note that you only need to do one `null` check now. The whole thing will be `false` if the first one is `null` and if the first one isn't `null` then any other `null` values will fail the equality test.

Comment: thanks for answer.But I also need to check that are these 3 elements equal

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about LINQ

Comment: @Hayk, I have updated my answer based on the additional information you provided.

Comment: I note that I turned from python to C# and there I could do checking like condition I wrote at first.Anyway thanks for thorough answer